# Correct path to sqlite database used by JAR imported into my Android app?

Tags: database, android, sqlite, path

My Android app is using a database through an API packaged in an external JAR. Since the JAR is opening/updating/closing the SQLite database file, do I need to make sure it uses its own package name instead of my own? Im getting errors where it fails to open the database file and Im guessing its because the package name Im telling it to use is incorrect: should it be using the package name in the JAR file?

Code that is opening the database:

```
    public AndroidSQLiteDataStore() throws SQLiteException {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        logger.information(TAG, "OPEN CONNECTION TO DATABASE " + Config.BN_ANDROID_DB_PATH);
        try {
            this.db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Config.ANDROID_DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            logger.error(TAG, e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Also tried poking around with the shell:

```
$ adb shell
$ ls
sqlite_stmt_journals
cache
sdcard
etc
system
sys
sbin
proc
logo.rle
init.sapphire.rc
init.rc
init.goldfish.rc
init
default.prop
data
root
dev
$ cd data
$ ls
opendir failed, Permission denied
$
```

Comment: I usually like to read people's comments though I see I have forgotten to mark a few as accepted. Ive fixed that now. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to list all your questions that are still marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the JAR is
>   opening/updating/closing the SQLite
>   database file, do I need to make sure
>   it uses its own package name instead
>   of my own?

JARs don't have package names from an Android standpoint.

Comment: So using the package name of my app in the path should work right?

I get an error when I try to open /data/data/mypackagename/databases/locker.db and I dont understand why.

Comment: We can't readily help with errors without seeing the error in question. Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to take a look at the Java stack trace. If that doesn't clear up the matter directly, edit your question, post the stack trace there, and if you think of it, add a comment onto this chain here so StackOverflow pings me that there's been an update (I don't think I'll find out if you just edit the issue).

Comment: OK, so the log shows this error:

    I/AndroidSQLLiteDataStore(29640): OPEN CONNECTION TO DATABASE /data/data/packagename/databases/locker.db  
    E/Database(29640): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/packagename/databases/locker.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed  
    E/AndroidSQLLiteDataStore(29640): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file  

The packagename in my manifest and used in the path is the same.

Comment: Q1. Is the code trying to open the database is in the same process (e.g., part of the same application)? Q2. Can you edit your issue to paste in the code where you are trying to open the database?

Comment: A1. Its part of the same app but the database code lives inside a JAR that I am importing and using in my application.

Comment: Well, that certainly looks OK. I usually use `SQLiteOpenHelper`, though that may not work in your case. Otherwise, it's not obvious to me why you are getting the error, assuming that static data member's value is correct.

Comment: Basically, the Config class just has static strings for various things like pathnames and URLs. So Im using something like "/data/data/packagename/databases/locker.db" as the path to the database. Should I be using a relative path instead of an absolute one? Or maybe there's a permissions issue Ive overlooked?

Comment: Im assuming that packagename that Im using in the path is what I have in my manifest?

Comment: More importantly, it's the directory where you find the stuff on the emulator (or device, if you could look there). You should see the /data/data/your.package.here directory in the File Manager of DDMS, for example.

Comment: @commonsWare: Eno edited his OP and it seems he has problem even accessing the data folder. I found some posts on SO describing this but on a real device though(no root access).

Comment: Is the folder normally accessible from the adb shell? If so, then Im assuming its a permissions problem. I am testing on a real device BTW.

Comment: On the emulator, yes. On a device, no. However, just because adb shell cannot access it does not mean your app cannot access it. When you encounter file-related problems like this, I advise you to roll back to the emulator until you get everything working.